# Child component not working in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to display a child component, but the output is a blank screen. Even title is not showing. I am new to angular please help.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

**Child Component**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  template: '<h1>Haa</h1>',

})
export class CAppComponent {

}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CAppComponent } from './child/child.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, CAppComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<!--The whole content below can be removed with the new code.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{title}}!!
  </h1>
  <app-test></app-test>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to register your component in `declarations`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, CAppComponent  <--------------
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
```

not imports.

Imports is used to import other modules that export components, like `CommonModule`.